# How is the SQL Query process in multiple Joins?

Tags: join

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
     LEFT JOIN table_2 
       ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID
     INNER JOIN table_3
       ON table_1.ID = table_3.ID
```

How SQL process this joins?
Does SQL join first table 1 and 2. Then joining this new supertable with table 3? Or does it moves the other way?

Answer (score 7):

The **logical** order of execution is what you describe:

- it starts with the `FROM` clause analyzing it:

  ```
    FROM table_1
         LEFT JOIN table_2 
           ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID
         INNER JOIN table_3
           ON table_1.ID = table_3.ID
  ```
- according to precedence rules it becomes:

  ```
    FROM   (   table_1
             LEFT JOIN 
               table_2 
             ON 
               table_1.ID = table_2.ID
           )
         INNER JOIN 
           ( table_3 )
         ON
            table_1.ID = table_3.ID
  ```
- So, yes it first (logically) does the `table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID` producing a "super" table.
- Then it does the second join between the "super" table and table_3.
- Then it goes to `SELECT` clause, which is essentially all the columns of the 3 tables in this order:

  ```
    SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*, table_3.*
  ```
- then it produces the result set.

The **actual** order of execution can be quite different though. The RDBMS (SQL Server or MySQL or Postgres or Oracle or DB2 or ...) it allowed to choose any order it seems fit, **as long as it produces the same result as the logical order of execution.**

- So it can rearrange the order of joins if allowed (this depends on complicated rules, whether the joins are LEFT/RIGHT/INNER/FULL, whether the joining conditions are arbitrary or the same as FOREIGN KEY constraint conditions, whether the joining columns have UNIQUE/PRIMARY constraints on the tables, etc.)
- It's not only the order of joins that is available but also different join methods (hash, merge, nested loop methods, etc) or using parallelization.
- It may also choose various execution paths depending on existing indexes on the tables joined in the query.
- How it decides which execution path to choose may depend on even more details, like statistics on the tables and indexes, size of the tables, width of the columns and many more optimizer/system settings.
- It also depend on the RDBMS and the version. Different RDBMS have different methods implemented (eg MySQL did not have hash join until recently I think, Postgres has implemented parallel queries only 2-3 years ago but has extensive indexes of different types, SQL Server has parallel queries since ages ago but some features are in Enterprise version only, etc) so the execution path chosen will likely differ from DBMS to DBMS, unless for very simple queries.

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't process the queries, it's the database engine (MySQL and SQL-Server are two of them) that examines them.  The way it will resolve the query nowadays depends on what it considers the cheapest way, decided upon by an "optimizer", by examining, amongs others, available indexes and amount of data needed to answer the query.  For the amount of data to be known, the data needs to be "analyzed" whenever large changes have been made.  The statistics needed to make those decisions can't be kept up to date for every change that is made, that would harm performance.